# Sampling vector across image

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, scipy

This might seem a bit strange, but I really feel like there should be a relatively straightforward solution to it. Basically I've got an image in the form of a 3D numpy array (x, y, color). I was following along with [this tutorial](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/) for a slightly different product area, and found that these methods did not extend well.

As a result, I'm making a modified edge detection algorithm for my use case. As of now this is just some basic signal processing on top of a 1d array. This works great if I only want to sample in the `x` and `y` directions, as I can just use the existing rows and columns of the array.

However, to determine orientation of these edges, I would like to be able to sample any arbitrary vector across the image below is an image to help illustrate:

[image: Image Sampling Predicament]

I tried hacking together something that would just append pixels as it crossed them, but it was inefficient, inelegant, and non-ideal in a number of ways. I feel like there must be some relatively elegant way of doing this.

Any ideas? The size of the sample across the vector doesn't really matter to me if that makes things any easier.

Comment: Additional, slightly unrelated question, does anybody know why my image isn't showing up?

Comment: Image shows up for me just fine.

Comment: @askewchan huh, weird.

Answer (score 1):

I would make an equation for the line you want to cut along, then make a mask around it and keep all pixels that come within some width of it.  For example, say you want a cut along `i = 2*j + 34`, where `i` and `j` are measured in pixels:

```
h, w = im.shape[:2]
width = 2 # width of slice in pixels, too narrow and it will have gaps
i, j = np.ogrid[:h, :w]
mask = np.abs(2*j + 34 - i) < width
im[mask]
```

Note that `im[mask]` will be a 2d array, since it should still have the colors.  It will be ordered so that the uppermost pixels are first, and the bottom pixels are last, opposite of that shown in your arrow, unless of course you have `origin=lower` in your plotting :)  And if several pixels are selected in each row (if `width > 1`), then they'll go left to right, so the shape for a slice like your drawing would be a tiny sequence of z's, and for the other direction, backwards z's (s's?).

Keep in mind that for an array there doesn't exist a diagonal slice without some weird zigzag (or alternatively, interpolation) no matter how elegant your implementation is.  You could rotate the image (by some algorithm) and take a horizontal slice.

Comment: So... I was thinking much more along the lines of interpolation here. Mostly because that zigzagging means disaster on edge boundaries, which is mostly what I'm working with here.

Answer (score 1):

Using the equation

```
 x2 = x1 + length * cos(θ)
 y2 = y1 + length * sin(θ)
```

where

```
θ = angle * 3.14 / 180.0
```

You can iterate through the pixel using angle and length like

```
int angle =45; //angle of iteration  
int length = 0; //Alternately you can skip the pixel by giving value other than 0 
Point P1(starX,startY); //Your starting point.
Point P2;//??

while(1){

  length++;
  P2.x =  (int)round(P1.x + length * cos(angle * CV_PI / 180.0));
  P2.y =  (int)round(P1.y + length * sin(angle * CV_PI / 180.0));

  if(P2_exceed_boundary()) break;
  do_Whatever_with_P2();

}
```

Comment: Umm... I don't think you mean to be incrementing angle?

Comment: @Slater Tyranus You are right it should be length, thanks for noticing me the mistake. I will edit it.